# LinkedIn API retrieve information after logging in

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

ok i'm a noob to PHP and with these lines of code i've managed to get the API working that you have to log in as a user

$redirect = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=r_fullprofile&state=state&redirect_uri=mysite";

header('Location: '. $redirect);

now i'm wondering after the redirect how can i retrieve that user his information to my site? because the only way i can find is using oAuth but they ask for a consumer_key and consumer_secret but i have no clue how to fill these to retrieve the skills with: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(skills) (that's how i did it with my own profile)

i've tried getting the example to work but it won't work in a way that i can extract stuff from ppl.

can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Where you supplied `&redirect_uri` is where LinkedIn will send back the message (success or fail). So on that page you can intercept the authorization token.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the difficulty and complexity beginners face I have faced it myself :) .Follow the below link i've written a PHP code and explained steps to creating new application on LinkedIn Developers.

http://infinityexist.wordpress.com/2014/08/25/how-to-run-linkedin-api-for-beginners/

All the Best